# Changing Parent Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a problem with my javascript that I can't quite explain. Here is the html:

```
<body>
<div id='slidecarousel' class='slide1' onclick='No functions can be here'>
<div id="sliderButton" onclick='pageSlider(this)'>Next Slide</div>
<div id='piece of slider...'></div>
<div...></div>
...
</div>
</body>
```

Here is the javascript and the error:

```
function pageSlider(elem)
{
    var pDiv = $(elem).parent('#slidecarousel')
    if ( pDiv.className.match(/(?:^|\s)slide1(?!\S)/) ){

**Uncaught TypeError: cannot call method 'match' of undefined**

         pDiv.className = "slide2";
    } else {
    pDiv.className = "SlideErr";
}
}
```

Comment: `pDiv` is a jQuery object, `className` is a property of DOM elements.

Comment: Why aren't you just using jQuery's `.hassClass()` method?

Comment: Please this check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pDiv is a jQuery object, NOT a DOM element so it doesn't have a className property.  You can get the first DOM element with:

```
pDiv[0]
```

So, just change this:

```
var pDiv = $(elem).parent('#slidecarousel')
```

to this:

```
var pDiv = $(elem).parent('#slidecarousel')[0];
```

---

As an additional change, this doesn't make a whole lot of sense:

```
var pDiv = $(elem).parent('#slidecarousel')
```

If you just want the `#slidecarousel` object, then just use:

```
var pDiv = $('#slidecarousel')[0];
```

because there can only be one `#slidecarousel` object in the whole page anyway.

---

Or, if you just want the parent of `elem`, then use this:

```
var pDiv = elem.parentNode;
```

---

Or, you could also use `.closest()` like this:

```
var pDiv = $(elem).closet(".slide1")[0];
```

Comment: why not `var pDiv = $('#slidecarousel')`

Comment: @ArunPJohny - I don't really understand what the OP is trying to do with `$(elem).parent('#slidecarousel')`.  The point of the answer is that they need to use `[0]` to get the DOM object before accessing `.className`.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's method for testing classes:

```
if (pDiv.hasClass("class1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
pDiv[0].className.match(
```

or

```
pDiv.attr("class").match(
```

Cheers